# PHP Check variable that contains null as string

Tags: php

I'm checking whether to enter an if statement and debugging the result of a function it turn out that it returns null as a string.

In my code I'm checking:

```
<?php if($_product->getData('attr1') || $_product->getData('attr2')): ?>
      Do stuf here
<?php endif; ?>
```

And 'attr2' returns 'null', a string with length equals to 4.

How can I check if the variable is null for real?

Comment: Is your problem that `getData()` returns `'null'` instead of `null`? Handle it there.

Comment: @simPod yes the problem is that, isn't there a way to check here in my template that the variable is null instead of 'null'?

Comment: You'd probably have to add a condition to check for `'null'`. IMO the proper way to handle this is to fix getData method to return `null`. It will ease your pain in all places where you use it then. Because what if `attr2` has really a `'null'` value?

Comment: @simPod is saying absolute right, you need to add another string comparison for `'null'` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'null'` is a string value that's why it is passing your checks. you need to check it like string value as well.

```
<?php if($_product->getData('attr1') || ($_product->getData('attr2') && strtolower($_product->getData('attr2')) != 'null' ) ): ?>
      Do stuf here
<?php endif; ?>
```

It is case specific, if you have `'null'`, `'Null'` or `NULL` string for only `attr2`